# Sessions + Objects

Tags: php

I'm working on a generic UCP, and I'm trying to store a user profile object within a session. The problem standing, is that I can't grab any data from it.

A few snippets,

**user.php**

```
public $data, $logs;
public $user_name;

function User($user_name) {

  this->user_name=$user_name;
  this->Fetch(); //CAN_USE_FETCH_FOR_UPDATES
}
function Fetch() {

  this->data=*; //SQL_DATA
  this->logs=*; //SQL_DATA
}
```

**functions.php**

```
function create_user($user_name) {

  require_once('./struct/user.php');
  $user = new User($user_name);
  $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
}
```

**main.php**

```
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
echo($user->user_name); //NOT_WORKING
echo($user->data['username']); //NOT_WORKING
```

I tried using print_r/var_dump on the session variable, and it prints the entire object. I just can't grab any data from it for whatever reason.

**print_r($user)**

```
(
[__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => User
[data] => Array
(
[id] => 1
[username] => Veritas
...
```

Comment: echo($user->data['username']); //NOT_WORKING It could be maybe that the name of the variable is 'user_name'?

Comment: 'data' is a SQL row array, as shown in the print_r(...) result. I can't retrieve any data from anything in the class using $user as a pointer.

Comment: why don't you want to serialise an object before saving it into session. http://www.php.net/manual/en/oop4.serialization.php

Comment: I was instructed that when moving any objects to a session variable, it will automatically serialize/unserialize. I've also stored the functions.php in a session, and I'm able to call functions from it just fine using the same logic. $driver=new Functions; $_SESSION['driver']=$driver; etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data retrieved from session isn't your object of class `User`. It's a generic object, and property `__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name` suggests it should be instance of class `User` but at the time object is created, PHP runtime does not know what `User` class is. Try load `User` class *before* you start session.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Created a workaround, my logic was flawed.